# Investment tracker allowing users to store investment information and later access it

Tags: python, python-3.x, finance, tkinter, sqlite

This investment tracker allows users to store investment information and later call upon it. This is a simple solution to making investing easier to maintain. This application has a simple login system that makes it possible for users to have multiple accounts or members of the same family to use the application on the same device. Any Thoughts to improve the user experience to make things easier?

```
'''
By Ronald Colyar 1/26/18
'''
#MODULES
import tkinter as tk
import sqlite3
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
#files
conn = sqlite3.connect('login.db')
c = conn.cursor()
conn2 = sqlite3.connect('investments.db')
c2 = conn2.cursor()


class SignUp:
    def __init__(self , master):
        self.master = master
        master.config(background = 'black')
        master.title(string = 'Sign Up window')
        master.iconbitmap('phantex.ico')
        #placing of the window
        w = 270
        h = 380
        ws = master.winfo_screenwidth()
        hs = master.winfo_screenheight()
        x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
        y =  (hs/2) - (h/2)
        master.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w,h,x , y))
        #creation of labels
        self.signup_label = tk.Label(master, text = 'Sign Up', fg = 'white' , bg = 'black', font = 'times 15 bold').grid(row = 0 , column = 0 ,columnspan = 2, sticky = 'we')
        self.firstname_label =tk.Label(master, text = 'First ( Atleast 3)', fg = 'white' , bg = 'black').grid(row = 1 , column = 0 , sticky = 'we')
        self.lastname_label =tk.Label(master, text = 'Last (Atleast 3)', fg = 'white' , bg = 'black').grid(row = 1 , column = 1 , sticky = 'we')
        self.username_label = tk.Label(master, text = 'Username  (Atleast 6)', fg = 'white' , bg = 'black').grid(row = 3 , column = 0 ,columnspan = 2, sticky = 'we')
        self.password_label = tk.Label(master, text= 'Password  (Atleast 6)' , fg = 'white' , bg = 'black').grid(row = 5 , column = 0 ,columnspan = 2,sticky = 'we')
        self.acctype_label  = tk.Label(master, text= 'Type of Investment account' , fg = 'white' , bg = 'black').grid(row = 7 , column = 0 ,columnspan = 2, sticky = 'we')
        self.titletype_label  = tk.Label(master, text= 'Title' , fg = 'white' , bg = 'black').grid(row = 9 , column = 0 ,columnspan = 2, sticky = 'we')
        self.buisness_label  = tk.Label(master, text= 'Buisness Name (Optional)' , fg = 'white' , bg = 'black').grid(row = 11 , column = 0 ,columnspan = 2, sticky = 'we')
        self.verification_label = tk.Label(master, text= 'Status:' , fg = 'white' , bg = 'black')
        self.verification_label.grid(row = 15 , column = 0 ,columnspan = 3, sticky = 'we')
        #creation of entrys
        self.firstname = ttk.Entry(master)
        self.firstname.grid(row = 2 , column = 0 , sticky = 'we')
        self.lastname = ttk.Entry(master)
        self.lastname.grid(row = 2 , column = 1 , sticky = 'we', padx = 5, pady = 5)
        self.username = ttk.Entry(master)
        self.username.grid(row = 4 , column = 0 ,columnspan = 2, sticky = 'we')
        self.password = ttk.Entry(master, show ='*')
        self.password.grid(row = 6 , column = 0 ,columnspan = 2, sticky = 'we')
        self.buisness = ttk.Entry(master)
        self.buisness.grid(row = 12 , column = 0 ,columnspan = 2, sticky = 'we')
        #creation of option menus
        self.options = \['Select' ,'Stock' ,'multiple', 'Real Estate' , 'Bonds' , 'intellectual property' , 'Buisness','Other'\]
        self.accvar = StringVar()
        self.accounttype = ttk.OptionMenu(master , self.accvar, *self.options ).grid(row = 8, column = 0 ,columnspan = 2, sticky = 'we')
        self.options2 = \['Dr.' , 'Mr.' , 'Mrs.' , 'Ms.' , 'Sir.','Miss.'\]
        self.titlevar = StringVar()
        self.titletype = ttk.OptionMenu(master , self.titlevar, *self.options2 ).grid(row = 10, column = 0 ,columnspan = 2, sticky = 'we')
        #creation of buttons
        submit = tk.Button(master, text = 'Submit', fg = 'white' , bg = 'black' , command = submit_mthd).grid(row = 13 , column = 0 , sticky = 'we' , columnspan =3)
        backwardsbutton = tk.Button(master , text = 'Back <--', fg = 'white' , bg = 'black' , command = signupback_mthd).grid(row = 14 , column = 0 , sticky = 'we' , columnspan =3)

    def change(self , verification):
        self.verification_label.configure(text =verification )

def submit_mthd():
    #storing the values in variables makes it a bit easier to read
    firstname_data = signup_obj.firstname.get()
    lastname_data = signup_obj.lastname.get()
    username_data = signup_obj.username.get()
    password_data = signup_obj.password.get()
    buisness_data = signup_obj.buisness.get()
    accounttype_data = signup_obj.accvar.get()
    title_data = signup_obj.titlevar.get()
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM login WHERE user =:user", {'user' : str(username_data)})
    contents = c.fetchall()

    #checking the length of the entrys
    if len(str(firstname_data))  < 3 or len(str(lastname_data)) < 3 or len(str(username_data)) < 6 or len(str(password_data))<6:
        signup_obj.change('Status: Please Fill Out Full Application')

    elif len(contents) > 0:
        signup_obj.change( 'Username Already Taken on this system')

    #saving all information and updating the status
    else:   
        c.execute("INSERT INTO login VALUES (?, ? , ?, ?, ? , ? , ?)", ((firstname_data) , (lastname_data) , (username_data) ,(password_data) ,  (accounttype_data) ,  (title_data) ,  (buisness_data)))
        signup_obj.change('Status : Account created')
        conn.commit()


class SignInGui:
    def __init__(self , master):
        self.master = master
        master.title(string = 'Sign In')
        master.resizable(width = False , height = False)
        master.iconbitmap('phantex.ico')
        #aesthetics
        master.config(background='black')
        photo = PhotoImage(file = 'Phantex.png')
        Phantex_image = tk.Label(master, image = photo, fg = 'white' , bg = 'black')
        Phantex_image.image = photo
        Phantex_image.grid(row =7  , column = 0 , sticky = 'we' )
        #placing of the window
        w = 370
        h = 250
        ws = master.winfo_screenwidth()
        hs = master.winfo_screenheight()
        x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
        y =  (hs/2) - (h/2)
        master.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w,h,x , y))
        #creation of entrys
        self.username = ttk.Entry(master)
        self.username.grid(row = 2 , column = 0 , sticky = 'we')
        self.password = ttk.Entry(master, show ='*')
        self.password.grid(row = 4 , column = 0 , sticky = 'we')    
        #creation of labels
        self.title = tk.Label(master, text = 'Investment Tracker',font = 'times 14 bold', fg = 'white' , bg = 'black' ).grid(row = 0 , column = 0 , sticky ='we' )
        self.username_label = tk.Label(master, text = 'Username', fg = 'white' , bg = 'black').grid(row = 1 , column = 0 , sticky = 'we')
        self.password_label = tk.Label(master, text= 'Password' , fg = 'white' , bg = 'black').grid(row = 3 , column = 0 , sticky = 'we')
        self.status_label =  tk.Label(master, text= None , fg = 'Red' , bg = 'black' , font = 'times 9')
        self.status_label.grid(row = 8 , column = 0 , sticky = 'we')
        #creation of buttons
        self.login_button = tk.Button(master, text = 'Sign In', fg = 'white' , bg = 'black' , command = signin_check).grid(row = 5, column = 0 , sticky = 'we')
        self.signup_button= tk.Button(master, text= 'Create An Account', command = signup_mthd, fg = 'white' , bg = 'black').grid(row = 6 , column = 0 , sticky = 'we')
        #making the mainwindow scale when resized
        master.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        master.grid_rowconfigure(1,weight=1)
        master.grid_rowconfigure(2,weight=1)
        master.grid_rowconfigure(3,weight=1)
        master.grid_rowconfigure(4,weight=1)
        master.grid_rowconfigure(5,weight=1)
        master.grid_rowconfigure(6,weight=1)
        master.grid_rowconfigure(7,weight=1)
        master.grid_rowconfigure(8,weight=1)
        master.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

class mainpagegui:

    def __init__(self , master):
        self.master = master
        master.resizable(width = False, height = True)
        master.iconbitmap('phantex.ico')
        w = 420
        h = 490
        ws = master.winfo_screenwidth()
        hs = master.winfo_screenheight()
        x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
        y =  (hs/2) - (h/2)
        master.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w,h,x , y))
        #creation of the menus
        self.titlebaroptions = tk.Menu(master)
        self.savemenu = tk.Menu(master,tearoff = False)
        self.savemenu.add_command(label = 'Save Investment' , command = save_inv_mthd)
        self.advancedmenu = tk.Menu(master,tearoff = False)
        self.advancedmenu.add_command(label = 'Advanced Investment Information' , command = advanced_mthd)
        self.removemenu = tk.Menu(master,tearoff = False)
        self.removemenu.add_command(label = 'Remove Investment Record' , command = remove_inv_mthd)
        #adding menus to the main bar
        self.titlebaroptions.add_cascade(label = 'Save Investment' , menu = self.savemenu)
        self.titlebaroptions.add_cascade(label = 'Advanced Statistics' , menu = self.advancedmenu)
        self.titlebaroptions.add_cascade(label = 'Remove Investment' , menu = self.removemenu)
        self.master.config(menu = self.titlebaroptions)

        #creation of labels
        self.Greeting = tk.Label(master ,text = usergreeting() ,bg= 'black', fg ='white').grid(row = 0 , column = 0 , sticky = W , columnspan = 2)
        self.price_label = tk.Label(master ,text = 'Price',bg= 'black', fg ='white').grid(row = 1 , column = 0 , sticky = 'we')
        self.date_label = tk.Label(master, text = 'Date',bg= 'black', fg ='white').grid(row = 1 , column = 1 , sticky = 'we')
        self.estimatedprofit_label = tk.Label(master ,text = 'Estimated Profit',bg= 'black', fg ='white').grid(row = 3 , column = 0 , sticky = 'we')
        self.aos_label = tk.Label(master, text = 'Amount of shares(Stock Investment)',bg= 'black', fg ='white').grid(row = 3 , column = 1 , sticky = 'we')
        self.seller_label = tk.Label(master, text = 'seller',bg= 'black', fg ='white').grid(row = 5 , column = 0 , sticky = 'we')
        self.buyer_label = tk.Label(master ,text = 'Buyer',bg= 'black', fg ='white').grid(row = 5 , column = 1 , sticky = 'we')
        self.pps_label = tk.Label(master ,text = 'Price per share(Stock Investment)',bg= 'black', fg ='white').grid(row = 7 , column = 0 , sticky = 'we')
        self.Lop_label = tk.Label(master ,text = 'Location of property(RealEstate)',bg= 'black', fg ='white').grid(row = 7 , column = 1 , sticky = 'we')
        self.dpr_label = tk.Label(master ,text = 'Dividend Pay Rate(Stock)',bg= 'black', fg ='white').grid(row = 9 , column = 0 , sticky = 'we')
        self.PI_label = tk.Label(master ,text = 'Passive Income',bg= 'black', fg ='white').grid(row = 9 , column = 1 , sticky = 'we')
        self.ID_label = tk.Label(master, text = 'ID Number(very important)',bg= 'black', fg ='white').grid(row = 11 , column = 0 , sticky = 'we')
        self.intERROR = tk.Message(master, text = None ,bg= 'black', fg ='red')
        self.intERROR.grid(row = 13, column = 0 , sticky = 'we')
        self.lenerror = tk.Label(master, text = None ,bg= 'black', fg ='red')
        self.lenerror.grid(row = 14, column = 0 , sticky = 'we')
        #creation of entrys
        self.price_entry = ttk.Entry(master)
        self.price_entry.grid(row = 2 , column = 0 , sticky = 'we')
        self.date_entry = ttk.Entry(master)
        self.date_entry.grid(row = 2 , column = 1 , sticky = 'we')
        self.estimatedprofit_entry = ttk.Entry(master)
        self.estimatedprofit_entry.grid(row = 4 , column =0 , sticky = 'we')
        self.aos_entry = ttk.Entry(master)
        self.aos_entry.grid(row = 4 , column = 1 , sticky = 'we')
        self.seller_entry = ttk.Entry(master)
        self.seller_entry.grid(row = 6 , column = 0 , sticky = 'we')
        self.buyer_entry = ttk.Entry(master)
        self.buyer_entry.grid(row = 6 , column = 1 , sticky = 'we')
        self.pps_entry = ttk.Entry(master)
        self.pps_entry.grid(row = 8 , column = 0 , sticky = 'we')
        self.Lop_entry = ttk.Entry(master)
        self.Lop_entry.grid(row = 8 , column = 1 , sticky = 'we')
        self.dpr_entry = ttk.Entry(master)
        self.dpr_entry.grid(row = 10 , column = 0 , sticky = 'we')
        self.PI_entry = ttk.Entry(master)
        self.PI_entry.grid(row = 10 , column = 1 , sticky = 'we')
        self.ID_entry = ttk.Entry(master)
        self.ID_entry.grid(row = 12 , column = 0 ,columnspan = 2,  sticky = 'we')
        #back button
        self.backbutton = tk.Button(master, command = mainpageback_mthd , text = 'Back<--',bg= 'black', fg ='white').grid(row = 15 , column = 0 , columnspan = 2, sticky = 'we')

        master.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        master.grid_rowconfigure(1,weight=1)
        master.grid_rowconfigure(2,weight=1)
        master.grid_rowconfigure(3,weight=1)
        master.grid_rowconfigure(4,weight=1)
        master.grid_rowconfigure(5,weight=1)
        master.grid_rowconfigure(6,weight=1)
        master.grid_rowconfigure(7,weight=1)
        master.grid_rowconfigure(8,weight=1)
        master.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

    def interrorchange(self , message):
        self.intERROR.configure(text =message )

    def lenerrorchange(self , message):
        self.lenerror.configure(text =message )

def usergreeting():

    global username_information
    title = c.execute("SELECT title FROM login WHERE user = :user" , {'user' : str(username_information)}) 
    #grabbing the title of user and commiting it to 'total'
    for row in title:
        total= 'Welcome ' + str(row\[0\])

    last = c.execute("SELECT last FROM login WHERE user = :user" , {'user' : str(username_information)}) 
    #grabbing the last name and adding it after the user's title 
    for row2 in last:
        total += row2\[0\]


    account_type = c.execute("SELECT accounttype FROM login WHERE user = :user" , {'user' : str(username_information)}) 
    for row3 in account_type:
        total+= '   Account Type:' + str(row3\[0\])
        return total

def main():
    global sign_in_window , obj
    sign_in_window = tk.Tk()
    sign_in_window.iconbitmap('phantex.ico')
    obj = SignInGui(sign_in_window)
    sign_in_window.mainloop()
def mainpage(bool):
    global sign_in_window, mainpage_gui , mainpage_window
    if bool == True:
        sign_in_window.destroy()

        mainpage_window =tk.Tk() 
        mainpage_window.config(background = 'black')
        mainpage_window.title(string = 'Main Page')
        mainpage_gui = mainpagegui(mainpage_window)

def signin_check():
    global obj , username_information
    username_information = obj.username.get()
    password_information = obj.password.get()
    #checking the database to see if the info matches
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM login WHERE password =? and user = ?" ,  (str(password_information) , str(username_information)))
    if c.fetchall() == \[\]:
        result=  False
        #update the user on the status of login
        obj.status_label.config(text = 'Incorrect password or username')
    else:
        result = True
    mainpage(result)
def signup_mthd():
    global  sign_up_window , sign_in_window ,signup_obj
    sign_in_window.destroy()
    sign_up_window = tk.Tk()
    sign_up_window.iconbitmap('phantex.ico')
    signup_obj = SignUp(sign_up_window )
def signupback_mthd():
    sign_up_window.destroy()
    main()
def mainpageback_mthd():
    global mainpage_window
    mainpage_window.destroy()
    main()
def combiner(category):
    global username_information
    placeholder = 0
    total = 0 
    #searching for the price of the user
    info = c2.execute("SELECT "+ category+ " FROM investments WHERE user = :user" , {'user' : str(username_information)})
    for row in info:
        #turning the row(tuple) , into a int
        placeholder = int(row\[0\])
        #adding all the results together
        total += placeholder
    return total


def advance_search_mthd(category , value):
    global username_information , information_box, search_box
    #removing whats currently in the box
    information_box.delete(0 , 'end')
    #searching for all investments
    results = c2.execute("SELECT * FROM investments WHERE "+str(category)+" = ?" , (value,))

    number_of_row = 0

    for row in results:
        number_of_row += 1

        information_box.insert(0 ,'#' + str(number_of_row)+ str(row) )
def single_search():
    advance_search_mthd('investment_id_number' , search_box.get())
def all_search():
    advance_search_mthd('user' , str(username_information))
def advanced_mthd():
    global information_box , search_box
    advanced_window = tk.Tk()
    advanced_window.iconbitmap('phantex.ico')
    advanced_window.config(background = 'black')
    advanced_window.title(string = 'Advance Statistics')


    #placement of window
    w = 1040
    h = 290
    ws = advanced_window.winfo_screenwidth()
    hs = advanced_window.winfo_screenheight()
    x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
    y =  (hs/2) - (h/2)
    advanced_window.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w,h,x , y))
    #creation of labels 
    overal_price_invested = tk.Label(advanced_window , text = str('Total Spent On investments :' + ' ' +str(combiner('price'))),bg= 'black', fg ='white').grid(row = 2 , column = 0  , sticky= 'we')
    estimated_profit =tk.Label(advanced_window , text = str('Total Estimated_profit :' + ' ' +str(combiner('estimated_profit'))),bg= 'black', fg ='white').grid(row = 3 , column = 0  , sticky= 'we')
    amount_of_shares =tk.Label(advanced_window , text = str('Total Shares :' + ' ' +str(combiner('amount_of_shares'))),bg= 'black', fg ='white').grid(row = 4 , column = 0  , sticky= 'we')
    price_per_share =tk.Label(advanced_window , text = str('Total Estimated_profit :' + ' ' +str(combiner('price_per_share'))),bg= 'black', fg ='white').grid(row = 5 , column = 0  , sticky= 'we')
    passive_income =tk.Label(advanced_window , text = str('Combined Passive income :' + ' ' +str(combiner('passive_income'))),bg= 'black', fg ='white').grid(row = 6 , column = 0  , sticky= 'we')
    search_label = tk.Label(advanced_window , text = 'Search for investment using id number',bg= 'black', fg ='white').grid(row = 8 , column = 0 , sticky = 'we')
    header = tk.Label(advanced_window , text = 'Price , Date, Estimated profit , amount of shares , seller, buyer , price per share , user , location of property , dividend price rate , passive_income , id number',bg= 'black', fg ='white').grid(row = 0 , column = 1 , sticky = 'we')
    #creation of listbox

    information_box = tk.Listbox(advanced_window , width = 50)
    information_box.grid(row = 1 ,column =  1 ,rowspan = 6, sticky = 'we')
    #creation of Entrys
    search_box = ttk.Entry(advanced_window)
    search_box.grid(row = 9 , column = 0 , sticky = 'we')
    #creation of buttons
    submit_button = tk.Button(advanced_window , text = 'Submit' ,bg= 'black', fg ='white', command = single_search)
    submit_button.grid(row = 11 , column = 0 , sticky = 'we')   
    all_info_button = tk.Button(advanced_window,text = 'Import all investments',bg= 'black', fg ='white', command =all_search )
    all_info_button.grid(row = 12 ,column = 0 , sticky = 'we')


def remove_algo():
    global username_information , main_entry , error_msg
    #checking to see if the investment is in the database
    c2.execute("""SELECT * FROM investments WHERE user= ? and investment_id_number = ?""" ,  (username_information, main_entry.get()))
    if c2.fetchall() == \[\]:
        #updating the user on the status of the request if there is no investment there
        error_msg.config(text = 'No Investment Under That ID number')
    else:
        error_msg.config(text = 'Investment Deleted')
        #updating the user on the status of the request if there is an investment there
        c2.execute("""DELETE  FROM investments WHERE user = ? and investment_id_number = ? """ , (username_information , main_entry.get()))
        conn2.commit()
def remove_inv_mthd():
    global main_entry ,error_msg
    #configuring window
    remove_window = tk.Tk()
    remove_window.title(string = 'Remove Window')
    remove_window.iconbitmap('phantex.ico')
    remove_window.config(background = 'black')
    w = 380
    h = 220
    ws = remove_window.winfo_screenwidth()
    hs = remove_window.winfo_screenheight()
    x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
    y =  (hs/2) - (h/2)
    remove_window.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w,h,x , y))


    #widgets
    main_message = tk.Message(remove_window , text = 'Welcome To the Delete section , where you can remove an investment, Keep in mind once you remove an investment it cannot be recovered' , font = 'times 13 bold ',bg= 'black', fg ='white')
    main_message.grid(row = 1, column = 0 , sticky = 'we')
    note_message = tk.Label(remove_window, text= 'NOTE : ENTER THE Investment ID , CHECK HELP FOR MORE INFO',bg= 'black', fg ='white')
    note_message.grid(row = 2, column = 0 , sticky = 'we')
    main_entry = ttk.Entry(remove_window)
    main_entry.grid(row= 3  , column = 0 , sticky = 'we')
    delete_button = tk.Button(remove_window ,text='Remove**' ,  command = remove_algo,bg= 'black', fg ='white')
    delete_button.grid(row = 4 , column = 0  , sticky = 'we')
    error_msg = tk.Label(remove_window , text = None ,bg= 'black', fg ='red' )
    error_msg.grid(row = 5 , column = 0 , sticky = 'we')


def intcheck(value):
    try:
        int(value)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False


def save_inv_mthd():
    global username_information , mainpage_gui
    #storing the values in variables makes it a bit easier to read
    price_data = mainpage_gui.price_entry.get()
    date_data = mainpage_gui.date_entry.get()
    estimated_profit_data = mainpage_gui.estimatedprofit_entry.get()
    amount_of_shares_data = mainpage_gui.aos_entry.get()
    seller_data = mainpage_gui.seller_entry.get()
    buyer_data = mainpage_gui.buyer_entry.get()
    price_per_share_data = mainpage_gui.pps_entry.get()
    location_of_propery_data =mainpage_gui.Lop_entry.get()
    dividend_price_rate_data = mainpage_gui.dpr_entry.get()
    passive_income_data = mainpage_gui.PI_entry.get()
    investment_id_data = mainpage_gui.ID_entry.get()
    intcheck_results = True
    len_results = True

    if len(price_data) < 3 or len(date_data)<3 or len(passive_income_data) <3 or len(seller_data)<3 or len(buyer_data)<3 or len(estimated_profit_data) <3 :
        len_results = False
    if intcheck(price_data) == False or intcheck(estimated_profit_data) == False or intcheck(amount_of_shares_data)== False or intcheck(price_per_share_data)== False or intcheck(passive_income_data) == False:
        intcheck_results = False

    if intcheck_results == False:
        mainpage_gui.interrorchange('ERROR #1 :Price,estimated profit,amount of shares,price per share,passive income must be all numbers no letters')
    if len_results == False:
        mainpage_gui.lenerrorchange('ERROR #2 :Must have 3 or more characters in all boxes')

    else: 
        mainpage_gui.interrorchange (None)
        mainpage_gui.lenerrorchange('SUCCESSFULLY SAVED')
        c2.execute("INSERT INTO investments VALUES (?, ? , ?, ?, ? , ? , ?, ? , ? , ? , ? , ?)", 
        ((price_data) , (date_data) , (estimated_profit_data) ,(amount_of_shares_data) ,  (seller_data) ,  (buyer_data) ,  (price_per_share_data) ,
        (username_information), (location_of_propery_data) , (dividend_price_rate_data)  , (passive_income_data), (investment_id_data) ))
        conn2.commit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

conn.close()
conn2.close()][1]
```

[image][image]

[image]

Comment: You do not need 2 different cursors for SQLite connections. A single sqlite file can contain several tables inside it. And from what I see from your code, you are just interested in 2 tables, namely `login` and `investments` with minor usage of `accounttype`. Put them together in a single `.db` file, and create just one cursor.

Comment: @hjpotter92 are you suggesting putting all information in one db by creating two tables in one db?

Comment: yes. you'll have a single connection and single cursor.

Comment: @hjpotter92 yea that makes sense , way simpler.Thanks